# How to pull image from json to html in angular js without using rest?

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to pull image from JSON database to show it in image slider.
JSON is:-

`{
       "items" : [
        {
          "img": "img/product1.JPG",
          "alt" : "Image 1"
        },
        {
          "img": "img/product2.JPG",
          "alt" : "Image 2"
        },
        {
          "img": "img/product3.JPG",
          "alt" : "Image 3"
        },
        {
          "img": "img/product4.JPG",
          "alt" : "Image 4"
        },
        {
          "img": "img/product5.JPG",
          "alt" : "Image 5"
        },
        {
          "img": "img/product6.JPG",
          "alt" : "Image 6"
        }
      ]
    }`

html:-

```
<div id="image_slider" class="img_slider">
     <img src={{items}} />
</div>
```

css:-
     `#image_slider .item{
         padding: 30px 0px;
          background: #a1def8;
          display: block;
          margin: 5px;
          color: #FFF;
          border-radius: 3px;
          text-align: center;
}`

controller:-
This is jquery code.I want to convert that code in AngularJs.I am new to angular.So can anyone help me in this?

```
//$scope.document.ready(function($scope) {
 app.directive('image_slide', function($scope) {

     $scope.document.ready(function($scope) {
  ("#image_slider").img_slider({
    jsonPath : 'data/imageSlider.json',
    jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess
  });

  function customDataSuccess(data){
    var content = "";
    for(var i in data["items"]){

       var imgs = data["items"][i].imgs;
       //var alt = data["items"][i].alt;

       content += "<img src=" + "" +imgs+ "/>";
      /* <img src="img/product1.JPG"/>*/
    }
    $("#image_slider").html(content);
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concepts you need to use here are [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

For example, you'd fetch your data like this:

```
$http.get('data/imageSlider.json')
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.images = data.items;
  });
```

And then you'd display it like this:

```
<img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{image.img}}" alt="{{image.alt}}" />
```

Here's a [full example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NVfK03AH0UPoojj321D8?p=preview).

Comment: thanks for answering previous question @Agop here is one more thing i am creating image slider so i want to use arrow button images in json data.I want to access them as arrow buttons on which i click the set of next images will come... one more question how can I pull only 3 images from middle out of 6.

Comment: In order to do that, you'll need to create some new scope variables and use them in your view. A lot of these topics are covered in the [Angular Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), so I highly recommend reading through it.